# Why do nuclei precess in magnetic fields?

Tags: magnetic-fields, quantum-spin, precession, nuclear-magnetic-resonance

I understand that a classical bar magnet will precess about the axis of an external magnetic field. Whilst researching NMR, I have read that nuclei with half-integer spin which are subject to an external magnetic field can occupy two possible states; spin-up and spin-down. In the spin-up state, the magnetic field generated by a nucleus is parallel to the external magnetic field, and in the spin-down state, the magnetic field generated by a nucleus is antiparallel to the external magnetic field.

Here is a diagram:

[image]

As you can see, the magnetic fields of the nuclei are *exactly* parallel or antiparallel to the external field. In my understanding, this means that they cannot precess about the external magnetic field. It seems invalid to use a model of precession in this case, yet the model is used successfully to explain NMR, what's going on?

Comment: The spin-up and spin-f

Comment: The spin-up and spin-down designations apply only to the components of nuclear spins in the z direction

Answer (score -1):

The nuclei precess because they have non-zero angular momenta that make force the nuclei to resist changing their state of motion. Hence, the nuclei don't completely align with the external magnetic field, and precess instead.